# Sampling. What is the difference between census and random sampling. How do you known how the researcher selects the sample

Tags: sampling

What is the difference between census sampling and random sampling. For example, a census sample of junior doctors in a 6 acute wards were recruited to a questionnaire survey.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a misconception in what you're asking for: a sample is only part of a population you wish to represent. A census is everyone in your population, so a census sample is not possible; you can have either a sample or a census.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The reason why I am asking is I am currently reviewing a research article and it says a census sample of professionals in a hospital. Hence my query?????

Comment: As far as I can see, there is nothing in my searching about a census sample. I asked my wife about this and we came to the conclusion that it might be like the U.S. census where they can't reach every person, so they get everyone they can and call it a census sample because they "practically" got everyone. That is not an official statistical phrase I'm familiar with, though.

Comment: Ok Thanks for your response. The article is actually a Uk research done in 2011 and I am doing a critical appraisal of the paper. The question was what was the sample frame? Just have to stick with census sample .